# CHECKING THE COLOR OF A WEB ELEMENT WITH SELENIUM

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation, instagram

I'm building an Instagram bot with Python + Selenium and I'm trying to get the fill attribute of an element (the like button) and make the bot like it if like_color != "#262626"

The goal of this code is to avoid unliking posts that are already liked.

```py
x7 = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div'

like_color = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x7).get_attribute("fill")
# #262626 means that the color is grey (not liked)
if like_color == '#262626':
    # like_post() is the function that gives likes
    like_post()
else:
    print('Post already liked')
```

I tried this way and many others but still got no result.. and when I ask the code to

```py
print(like_color)
```

it returns 'None'

If you got any knwoledge please help

Comment: Could you share all the label of the element you want to get?

Comment: It will help us to make you resolved if you share the HTMl DOM code

Comment: Idk what is HTML DOM code :)